# Set secret in cookie-parser or express-session?

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, express

When using the `cookie-parser` and `express-session` with Express 4, I can put the "secret" in either the cookie-parser or the express-session. **Is there any recommendations whats right here?**

It seems that if I put the secret in the `cookie-parser`, the coockie end up in `req.signedCookies` ...and if I put the secret in the `express-session`, the coockie end up in `req.cookies`.

Comment: As far as `req.signedCookies` is concerned, a signed cookie will be placed in `req.signedCookies` so there is no ambiguity between `req.cookies` and `req.signedCookies`. The community seems to favor the secret being placed in `express-session`. I do not think there is an underlying difference whether it is placed in `express-session` of `cookie-parser`, as long as the middleware order is correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [when should I use cookie-parser with express-session?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27961320/when-should-i-use-cookie-parser-with-express-session)