# when should I use cookie-parser with express-session?

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, express, session-cookies

In most ExpressJs example, I found using `cookie-parser` with `express-session`.

If I could access session data with `req.session.name` without it, in what case ( or benefits ) should I be using `cookie-parser`?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

For future humble coders, that will stumble upon this - I'm posting an up-to-date answer:

As the official description of `express-session` middleware says here: [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session)

> Since version 1.5.0, the `cookie-parser` middleware no longer needs to
>   be used for this module to work. This module now directly reads and
>   writes cookies on req/res. Using `cookie-parser` may result in issues if
>   the secret is not the same between this module and `cookie-parser`.

Therefore, just use express-session middleware and have a nice day.

Comment: According to Express' own security guidelines express-session is not production ready and should not be used: https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-security.html#use-cookies-securely

Comment: @ViggoV I think you mean this line `By default, it uses in-memory storage and is not designed for a production environment` ? It talks not about whole `express-session` being not prod ready, but rather about not using default in-memory storage for production, together with `express-session` you should use session store compatible with your db for persistent cookie storage and it all will be fine.

Comment: So cookie-parser can't be used with express-session? what if I need to both read cookie and maintain session data?

Comment: @Benny no idea if they'll conflict or not tbh. Personally I would've just checked if there's a session reading api/parsed cookies exposed on express-session.

Comment: @Benny from the express-session main page, it sounds like they will only conflict if the secret is different between the two modules - "Using cookie-parser may result in issues if the secret is not the same between this module and cookie-parser"

Answer (score 3):

In addition to providing simple cookie parsing functionality, the `cookie-parser` middleware enables signed cookies which can be referenced by other middleware components, using an optional `secret` attribute.

Why would you want signed cookies? [This question addresses that well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240246/signed-session-cookies-a-good-idea)

Comment: The documentation at https://github.com/expressjs/session seems to indicate it supports a signed cookie on its own. Am I missing something?